# Difference between "No good at all" and "Not good at all"?

Tags: word-difference

I can't understand the difference between the following:

> 1. No good at all
> 2. Not good at all

And I hear them when I'm listening music or watching a movie, bla bla. But it seem to be same meaning?

Can you show me how to use them with the rightly way?

Comment: See [*no good*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/no-good). *not good* is just the negation of *good*. Some examples using these phrases should be added to your question. This helps to write a more focused answer.

Answer (score 3):

From [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/e/not-good-vs-no-good/) (I suggest, you read the article once after this) :

> When good is used as a noun, no can quantify or modify it.

So when you use "No good" you are basically measuring how good is something, And what is the outcome. Another meaning of "No good ..." is when something has "**No profit**" or when something is "**Not that good, Useless or worthless**" and **"No good at all" can mean "Totally useless or worthless"**.
Some examples of "No good ..." from  the same [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/e/not-good-vs-no-good/) article:

- *No good can come from this evil plan* -> The success rate is Zero or it is no profit
- *His suspicious behavior indicated that he was up to no good* -> Something not counting as a good act (But not 100% bad)
- *The no-good dishwasher stopped working again* -> Not doing well
- *Jack was always in trouble. He was just no good*
- *The spare tire is no good. It has a hole in it*

> "**Not**" acts to disqualify something from being good.

Some examples are:

- *Chocolate is not good for dogs*
- *That dinner was not good*
- *Mary’s chances of finishing the race after twisting her ankle are not good*

So when you say "Not good at all" you are basically saying "Totally Bad".

An similar question is asked here : [english.stackexchange.com](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64510/when-to-use-no-good-when-to-use-not-good)

Sorry for my bad edit.

Comment: could you give a couple of example sentences to further clarify your explanation? Also, to distinguish which one to use when...

Comment: tks u so much <3